# Writing a generic function that could filter users based on different predicates

Tags: scala

Say I have a function like this:

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String, age: Int, Salary: Double)

def findRichUsers(users: Seq[User]): Seq[User] = 
  users.filter(x => x.Salary > 100000)
```

Is it possible that I can modify this so I pass in a predicate that would could support:

1. where salary > 100000
2. where age between 10 and 20
   etc.

Basically want to be able to pass in a custom predicate so I can filter.

Comment: Yes, just ask for a **function** just exactly as `filter`, `def findUsers(users: Seq[User])(p: User => Boolean): Seq[User] = users.filter(p)` ... which opens the question to what would be the use of such **method** over just calling `filter` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can create something like an *implicit class* for your *users filtering operations*:

```
implicit class UsersFilterOps(users: Seq[User]) {
  def findByPredicate(p: User => Boolean): Seq[User] = users.filter(p)

  def findRichUsers: Seq[User] = findByPredicate(_.salary > 100000)
  def findBetweenAge(lowBound: Int, upperBound: Int): Seq[User] =
    findByPredicate(u => u.age >= lowBound && u.age <= upperBound)
}
```

and after use it:

```
import ${your.package}.${some.object}.UsersFilterOps

val users: Seq[User] = Seq(User(0, "John", 19, 3010.0), User(1, "Sarah", 39, 143030.0))
users.findRichUsers // return Seq[User]
users.findBetweenAge(10, 20) // return Seq[User]
users.findByPredicate(_.name == "John") // return Seq[User]
```

but it looks too excessively, same operations without helping functions:

```
users.filter(_.salary > 100000)
users.filter(u => u.age >= lowBound && u.age <= upperBound)
users.filter(_.name == "John")
```

Second way has almost the same number of symbols and more readable and without any classes, you don't need to looking for some util functions. So, I would prefer explicit lambda expressions instead of so little unification.